# Error in Import Resource file in bean-servlet.xml file

Tags: spring, oracle-coherence

While configure the oracle coherence application in my system I will get below road blocks of my application. 
    I posted bean-servlet.xml file and Log file.Can anybody give reply
    Thanks in advance.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

      <!-- Spring MVC configuration -->

      <context:component-scan base-package="com.seovic.samples.bank.web.controllers"/>

       <bean id="beanNameViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
      </bean> 

      <bean id="htmlViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
      </bean>

        <bean id="account"      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
      <bean id="accounts"     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
      <bean id="transactions" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
      <bean id="profile"      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>

    <!--   application configuration-->

      <bean id="bankManager" class="com.seovic.samples.bank.services.CoherenceBankManager"/>

      <bean id="testDataCreator" class="com.seovic.samples.bank.TestDataCreator">
        <property name="bankManager" ref="bankManager"/>
      </bean>  
    <import resource="classpath:repository-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:coherence-cache-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:coherence-tools.properties"/>
    <import resource="classpath:coherent-bank-pof-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:extend-proxy-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:log4j.properties"/>
    <import resource="classpath:persistence-context.xml"/>
     <import resource="classpat:tangosol-coherence-override-dev.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:tangosol-coherence-override.xml"/>
    </beans>
```

and I got below exception after deploy the application in JBOSS Server.

```
    10:55:08,145 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [repository-config.xml]
    10:55:08,147 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:repository-config.xml]
    Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/bank-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [repository-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [repository-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:192) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124) [spring-web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) [spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467) [spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397) [spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [repository-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [repository-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        ... 34 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [repository-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:141) [spring-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        ... 38 more

    10:55:08,159 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
    10:55:08,163 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/OracleCoherenceSampleApplication]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) JBWEB000289: Servlet bank threw load() exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [repository-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:141) [spring-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149) [spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124) [spring-web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93) [spring-web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130) [spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467) [spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397) [spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127) [org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)


    10:55:08,471 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "OracleCoherenceSampleApplication.war" (runtime-name : "OracleCoherenceSampleApplication.war")
    10:55:09,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
    10:55:09,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
    10:55:09,331 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started in 10194ms - Started 479 of 543 services (62 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: What don't you understand in "class path resource [repository-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist"?

Comment: Thanks for your response,repository-config.xml file under WEB-INF folder. Am I Correct?

Comment: Well, obviously you are not, since you get this error message. The classpath of a web-app is composed of the WEB-INF/classes directory and of all the jar files under WEB-INF/lib. WEB-INF is thus not part of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If all xml config files are inside /WEB-INF/xyz.xml folder then please import them as below,

```
<import resource="/WEB-INF/xyz.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

After add the under the /WEB-INF folder than import all resource files I will get below error.
    I attached imported resource statements and log file

Resource statements are added here

```
<import resource="/WEB-INF/repository-config.xml"/>
<import resource="/WEB-INF/coherence-cache-config.xml"/>
<import resource="/WEB-INF/coherence-tools.properties"/>
<import resource="/WEB-INF/coherent-bank-pof-config.xml"/>
<import resource="/WEB-INF/extend-proxy-config.xml"/>
<import resource="/WEB-INF/log4j.properties"/>
<import resource="/WEB-INF/persistence-context.xml"/>
 <import resource="/WEB-INF/tangosol-coherence-override-dev.xml"/>
<import resource="/WEB-INF/tangosol-coherence-override.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Log files
    12:35:53,287 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [/WEB-INF/repository-config.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/bank-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from URL [jndi:/default-host/OracleCoherenceSampleApplication/WEB-INF/WEB-INF/repository-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException

Comment: Can any body please response and thanks in advanced.